# Finding two Vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector `S` of size say 100x1. Sub-vectors `A` and `B` are created using `S`, say `A=S(1:50)` and `B=S(5:55)`. Note the shift in the elements in `A` and `B`. A resultant vector is generated `R=a*A + b*B`.

Now the problem is `a`, `b`, `R` and the shift between `A` and `B` are given. How to calculate `A` and `B`?

Comment: What are `a` and `b`, arbitrary coefficients?

Comment: The brute-force method would be to try each possible position for A and B, calculate the product with a and b and see if they match R. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Is `S` also given?

Comment: a and b are arbitrary coefficients.

S is not given.

Brute force is not feasible, as my R vector can be 10000x1 too.

Answer (score 3):

You have an underdetermined system of equation. So you cannot get the exact result. But matlab is totally able to estimate the solution of such a system of equation:

```
% Define the parameters
start = 10;
offset = 2;
len = 20;
a = 5;
b = 25;
% Create A and B from a random array S.
S = randi(30,1,100);
A = S(start:start+len-1);
B = S(start+offset:start+offset+len-1);
% We compute R
R = a*A+b*B;
% We create our system of linear equation:
M = cat(2,diag(ones(len,1)*a),zeros(len,offset))+cat(2,zeros(len,offset),diag(ones(len,1)*b));
% We solve the system
S_theta = (M\R.').'
```

Let's compare S_theta to S:

```
S_theta(offset+1:end)-B
```

Result:

[image]

Noticed that the result will be better if:

1. The offset is small (less unknows in the system of equation)
2. The difference between a and b is big.

When we do:

```
M\R.'
```

Matlab solve the system `Mx = R`, since `M` is underdetermined (we have `len` equations for `len+offset` unknows) then matlab use a `QR Solver` that find minimum-norm-residual solution to `Ax = B` type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have a linear system with a number of variables equaling `numel(R)+shift` and a number of equations equaling `numel(R)`.  I don't think it's possible to get what you want, since there are always more unknown variables than you have equations:

```
% First chain of variables
R(1) = a*S(1)+b*S(5); %One equation, two unknowns
R(5) = a*S(5)+b*S(9); %Two equations, three unknowns
R(9) = a*S(9)+b*S(13); %Three equations, four unknowns

% Second chain of variables
R(2) = a*S(2)+b*S(6); %Four equations, six unknowns
R(6) = a*S(6)+b*S(10); %Five equations, seven unknowns

% etc.
```

Comment: The constraint that the elements of `S` multiplied by `a` and those multiplied by `b` are always a constant index offset from each other - that would probably allow you to brute force the solution if `S` wasn't too large

Comment: That assumes a known `S`.  The question as stated specifies "`a`, `b`, `R` and shift between the A and B is given".  I'll ask OP for clarification.

Comment: The question literally starts "I have a vector S", so that might be known too

Comment: S is not given.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you don’t know S, then I think your problem can’t be solved.

Answer (score -2):

Slap `shift` zeroes on the front (resp. back) of S, multiply the former by `a` and the latter by `b`, and add them together.  This reduces the problem to a substring search.  You can either brute force that or use something more sophisticated; see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm